# Rows are deleted without using delete query

Tags: mysql, triggers, delete-row

I have a strange problem in my database. Rows are deleted when they are updated. I don't use delete query anywhere. I have an history log which logs data updation. I can find the particular row after updation on the log also (I have old data and updated data). But after that something happens. I can't figure out. The particular row is missing.

I have a update trigger:

```
    IF (NEW.PlanDateVisite<>OLD.PlanDateVisite)THEN
    BEGIN
        -- INSERT INTO ReportPlanHisto (Report_Id,PlanDateVisite) VALUES(OLD.Id,New.PlanDateVisite); -- Commented
    END;
    END IF;
```

Please Help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this peace of sql code for BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER?

Comment: You just work only on DB and sql query? Or you use java or C#, php...to execute update befor trigger fire?

Comment: @mirkobrankovic: Its after update trigger..

CREATE TRIGGER `Report_Update_CreateWorkflow` AFTER UPDATE ON `report` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  
  
  IF (NEW.PlanDateVisite<>OLD.PlanDateVisite)THEN
  BEGIN
   -- Commented Lines.. 
  END;
  END IF;
  
   END;

Comment: @PhongVo: I use it with C#.